# Carrier wave storing images as assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Iam trying to scrape several product website and build a catalogue of them. I want to download the image of the products using carrier wave and I will be using heroku for hosting. As herkou doesn’t provide is own file system. I was planning on using the downloaded images as assets instead of using a S3 account. can it be done? It seems practical to do is as i will scraping only once in 3 months or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this; you'd simply scrape in development, and add the images to your assets. With this, you won't want to use carrierwave, but instead your normal image_tag.

For example, for products, rather than mounting an uploader, you'd have a file_name attribute, and then do something like this to render

```
<%= image_tag(@product.file_name) %>
```

Concerns: Heroku has a maximum slug size for your app. That's assets + code + gems. Generally, the apps I run have a slug size around 50 meg. So you'll be limited in total size.

Comment: can you please edit your answer on pointers for how to get the file path for the model?

Comment: @djd why would you need that?

Comment: each model object is mapped to a image so i can easily get the path for the image

Comment: <%= image_tag(@product.whatever_you_want_to_name_this_method) %>